# verisign G5 root certificate checking

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate

Can somebody let me know how to check my server has VeriSign G5 root certificate installed. I have executed the following command

```
openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts
```

and it return the following result

issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3 . It means my server installed with VeriSign G3 root certificate?

Server : CentOS 5